# HTML download link opens mp3 file instead of downloading it

Tags: html

Here's my html:

```
<a class="btn fa fa-download" href="https://media.radiofrance-podcast.net/podcast09/11701-23.10.2023-ITEMA_23528507-2023C16756S0296-21.mp3" download="synode 2023 : vent de réforme sur l’église ?.mp3">Download</a>
```

This link streams the mp3, instead of downloading it... I use the class to make the link look like a button.

How can I make it download the file with the name defined above?

PS:
I'm already using the `<a>` element with the ***download*** attribute, and it doesn't do what I want. So, this isn't a exact duplicate of the suggested question, even though it has some similarities.

Comment: Cross-origin `download` anchors generally don’t work in this way for security reasons, except if the target server responds to the request with a specific `Content-Disposition` header value. [Relevant W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#downloading-resources)

Comment: @esqew Thanks. So, should I use javascript to do this then? (I'm new to frontend)

Comment: The linked duplicate has a JavaScript-based workaround for a very specific type of target file (not audio); since you ostensibly don’t control the server responding to the target URL your options are pretty limited even with the use of JavaScript. Arbitrarily triggering file downloads (especially cross-origin downloads) on behalf of a user is generally a no-no for security and UX both, which is why browsers generally limit such behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually an anchor element with a download attribute would be expected to download. However, in this case, as it was pointed out by user @esqew in a comment, it may not be the case sometimes...

The way I solved this was to create an new endpoint in my web app,
and then let the backend deal with this request. In this we're able to download the file, choose a filename and a file path where to download file (or move the file too)...